# Соединить элементы массива А в один элемент массива Б

Tags: c++, массивы, qt

Добрый день! Дано: `qlineedit` данные из которого записываются в `QByteArray`. Вводимые данные имеют вид "`000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000`". Т.к. в QByteArray элементы хранятся в виде [1]0 [2]0 [3]0 ... мне необходимо для работы "слить" эти элементы в один элемент другого массива. Т.е.

```
Б[0]=A[0]; // результат 0
Б[0]+=A[1]; // результат 00
Б[0]+=A[2]; // 000
```

... для всех элементов пропуская пробелы.
При том что данные с которыми я работаю в итоги имею тип `unsigned int`. 
ниже приведена моя попытка это решить, но у меня получается какой-то трэш.

```
QByteArray m = ui->lineEdit->text().toLatin1().data();

unsigned char ch[9];

for(int i =0; i<12; ++i)
{
     if(m[i]==' ')
          m[i]=m[i+1];
ch[i]=m[i];
ch[i]+=m[i+1];
ch[i]+=m[i+2];

}
```

Comment: Распишите более подробно требуемый результат.

Comment: То есть вам нужно в нулевой элемент некоего массива записать сумму всех элементов другого массива?

Comment: нет не сумма а именно 3 элемента т.е. ch[i] = "000";

Comment: @Akuma925 То есть B[i] = A[i * 3] + A[i * 3 + 1] + A[i * 3 + 2]? Собственно, правильная постановка вопроса уже содержит ответ.

Comment: Владимир, разверните ответ, не пойму как это?

Comment: @Akuma925, не вводите людей в заблуждение. Сначалы Вы пишете: "Дано: qlineedit данные из которого записываются в QByteArray", но затем записываете данные **из** QButeArray.

Comment: @Akuma925 чтобы развернуть ответ ВАМ нужно четко сформулировать что именно вы хотите.

Comment: QByteArray x("free");
 QByteArray y("dom");
 x.append(y);
 // x == "freedom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

struct Summ{
    unsigned int operator()(unsigned int i, char c) const{
        return i + (c - '0');
    }
};

int main(){
    char data[] = "123 300 022 050 090 001 000 010 030"; //QByteArray data;
    int size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(char);                //data.size();
    std::vector<unsigned int> result;

    const char *begin = &data[0];                        //data.data();
    const char *end = &data[size];

    while(begin < end){
        result.push_back(std::accumulate(begin, begin + 3, 0, Summ()));
        begin += 4;
    }

    for(int i : result){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

http://cpp.sh/4pwo4